# Using egit with github and eclipse 3.8.1 on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: eclipse, egit, ubuntu-13.10

I am new to eclipse, and I can't figure otu how to set up egit properly to work with github. I made a new local repository, and I've commited some changes, but now I want to get all this code onto github. What should I do? I can't find a solution in the eclipse wiki. I have a github account.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice demo that show you step by step [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U1kXlahkwd4)

What you want to do is pulling up repository in eclipse from `window -> show view -> other` (then find the repository) 
After you did that you go to master branch and configure remote then add your SSH key under your github account. Go to your eclipse git destination from remote enter your git account URL, username, password, repository path. All you need to do after that just hit the push.